# Site title not showing. What can I do?

Tags: title

My WordPress site's title not showing. It's just displaying the domain like,  *www.example.com*.

Please suggest how to display the proper title tag.

Answer (score 7):

Add this code to your functions.php

```
if ( !function_exists( 'yourtheme_setup' ) ) {
    function yourtheme_setup() {
        /*
         * Let WordPress manage the document title.
         * By adding theme support, we declare that this theme does not use a
         * hard-coded <title> tag in the document head, and expect WordPress to
         * provide it for us.
         */
        add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
    }

    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'yourtheme_setup' );
}
```

Or, if your functions.php already have `after_setup_theme`, just add the line `add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );` into your  `after_setup_theme`. ([Source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_theme_support/#title-tag))

Comment: Of note: if you add this, but you have already included a title tag in your header.php (in an effort to figure out what's going on perhaps), then this will have no effect.